# Sort vector of pointers to obcjects by value of property of these objects

Tags: c++, sorting, pointers, object, vector

In class Manager I have these methods:

```
void Manager::SortElementsById()
{
    sort(world->GetElements().begin(), world->GetElements().end(), compareById);
}

bool compareById(const Element* element1, const Element* element2)
{
    return element1->Id < element2->Id;
}
```

world is a pointer to the object of class World. Class World contains:

```
vector<Element*> elements; 
vector<Element*> World::GetElementss()
{
    return this->elements;
}
```

Class Element contains:

```
int Id;
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Why it doesn't work? I have following error: "Error  C2065   'compareById': undeclared identifier"
2. Ultimately I want to have Id (in class Element) private and return value of these field by public method GetId(). It is illigal when i want to execute this method on const object so I have no idea what can I do to sort these vector in these conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have following error: "Error C2065 'compareById': undeclared identifier"

Like always, `compareById` must be declared before you use it.  (Unless it's a member of the same class as an in-class function, but it doesn't seem to be a class member at all.)

> It is illigal when i want to execute this method on const object

Sounds like you just need to make your function a const member function.  Declare it like

```
int GetId() const;
```

and you will be allowed to call it on `const` objects.

Comment: That error was actually caused by wrong order. But now, when i execute SortElementsById() method I have runtime error:  "Expression: vector iterator incompatible".

Comment: That's because `GetElements()` returns a copy of the vector, not the same vector, so `world->GetElements().begin()` and `world->GetElements().end()` are iterators from two different vectors.  `GetElements()` should return by reference.